# PHP date calculate if startdate is greater than 18 months away

Tags: php, date, time

I have a simple php function which lists the months in order from a preset start date to the current date as below:

```
$this_date=date('F Y', time());
$startdate="1 December 2012";

function printMonths($var)
{
    $start = strtotime($var);
    $now = strtotime("Now");
    while ($now > $start)
    {
            echo date("F Y n", $now);
            echo "|";
            $now = strtotime("-1 month", $now);
    }       
}

$return_months=printMonths($startdate);
```

What I need to do is find out if the start date is greater than 18 months from the present day and if so set a new start date from 18 months ago. (All data is erased from the database once it is exactly 19 months old). I have set up a variable `$this_date` but not sure of the correct syntax to compare this with `$startdate`.

Answer (score 2):

Using PHP's `DateTime` objects allows you to get the difference in months between two dates quite easily. For example:

```
$start = new DateTime('1 December 2012');
$end = new DateTime('today');
$diff = $start->diff($end);
```

The `$diff` object will then hold all the data you'll need:

```
object(DateInterval)[3]
  public 'y' => int 0
  public 'm' => int 1
  public 'd' => int 16
  public 'h' => int 0
  public 'i' => int 0
  public 's' => int 0
  public 'invert' => int 0
  public 'days' => int 46
```

You can then either match `$diff->y == 1 && $diff->m >= 6` or `$diff->y > 1` or a certain amount of `$diff->days` to see if the data is "too old".

**Update**

If you want to list the "last 18 months" (starting from December 2012), you can use the `DatePeriod` class. For example:

```
$start = new DateTime('1 December 2012');
$today = new DateTime('today');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
$range = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $today);

foreach($range as $date) {
    $diff = $today->diff($date);
    if(($diff->y == 1 && $diff->m >= 6) || $diff->y > 1) {
        break; // Stop iterations if more than 18 months.
    }
    echo $date->format('F Y'); // Prints December 2012 and January 2013
}
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I set the new start date. Basically I want to list up to 18 months from the present month as long as there is a cut off point at 1 December 2012 where it ceases to list earlier months.

Comment: Thanks OldSkool - I need it the other way round though where in 18 months time it will start to knock off the earlier dates (eg December 2012). Therefore in 18+ months time December 2012 will disappear and a new start date will be set of January 2013 - if that makes sense :)